# Angular 6 tour of heroes tutorial - how to add more properties in HTTP post Observable function

Tags: angular

I added description property to the Hero model beside id and name
hero.ts:

```
export class Hero{
 id: number;
 name: string;
 description: string;
}
```

Now in the HTTP part in the tutorial, I am trying to add a new hero with the function they gave in the tutorial:

src/app/heroes/heroes.component.html (add):

```
<div>
  <label>Hero name:
    <input #heroName />
  </label>
  <!-- (click) passes input value to add() and then clears the input -->
  <button (click)="add(heroName.value); heroName.value=''">
    add
  </button>
</div>
```

src/app/heroes/heroes.component.ts (add):

```
add(name: string): void {
  name = name.trim();
  if (!name) { return; }
  this.heroService.addHero({ name } as Hero)
    .subscribe(hero => {
      this.heroes.push(hero);
    });
}
```

src/app/hero.service.ts (addHero):

```
/** POST: add a new hero to the server */
addHero (hero: Hero): Observable<Hero> {
  return this.http.post<Hero>(this.heroesUrl, hero, httpOptions);
}
enter code here
```

What should I add to which function in order to push hero description?

Answer (score 0):

Add an input field to the HTML and extend the actions after clicking the button

src/app/heroes/heroes.component.html:

```
<div>
  <label>Hero name:
    <input #heroName />
  </label>
  <label>Hero description:
    <input #heroDescription />
  </label>
  <!-- (click) passes input value to add() and then clears the input -->
  <button (click)="add(heroName.value, heroDescription .value); heroName.value=''; heroDescription.value =''">
    add
  </button>
</div>
```

Adjust add() function so it takes the description as a parameter and adds it to the hero object. Depending on whether description is optional or not you can alter the if-statement.

src/app/heroes/heroes.component.ts:

```
add(name: string, description: string): void {
  name = name.trim();
  description = description.trim();
  if (!name || !description) { return; }
  this.heroService.addHero({ name, description} as Hero)
    .subscribe(hero => {
      this.heroes.push(hero);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to instantiate an Hero :

```
private _hero :Hero=new Hero();
```

and to bind it :

```
<div>
    <label>Hero name:
      <input [(ngModel)]="_hero.name" />
    </label>
    <label>Hero description:
      <input [(ngModel)]="_hero.description"/>
    </label>
    <!-- (click) passes input value to add() and then clears the input -->
    <button (click)="add()">
      add
    </button>
  </div>
```

and in the add you can send an Hero : here console log for demonstrate

```
add(): void {
    console.log(this._hero.name  + this._hero.description);
    }
```